# Why does "($(this).css('opacity')==.3)" not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create an if statement in jquery that checks to see if the opacity is .3, but it does not
work.

```
if ($(this).css('opacity')==.3) {$(this).fadeTo(500,1);}
```

Am I formatting the opacity incorrectly? I also tried `0.3` to no avail.

**Background:**

I'm working with a fade effect, where an objects fades in when you scroll past it and fades out when you scroll up.

myfunkyside kindly showed me how to do this here: [Fade In on Scroll Down, Fade Out on Scroll Up - based on element position in window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694385/fade-in-on-scroll-down-fade-out-on-scroll-up-based-on-element-position-in-win/26697397#26697397)

myfunkyside's original jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b7qnrsrz/1/

In this instance, the fade goes from 0 opacity to 1 and back. I want to go from .3 to 1 and back instead.

I tried to replace

```
if (objectBottom < windowBottom) {
    if ($(this).css('opacity')==0) {$(this).fadeTo(500,1);}
} else { //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
    if ($(this).css('opacity')==1) {$(this).fadeTo(500,0);}
}
```

with

```
if (objectBottom < windowBottom) {
    if ($(this).css('opacity')==.3) {$(this).fadeTo(500,1);}
} else { //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
    if ($(this).css('opacity')==1) {$(this).fadeTo(500,.3);}
}
```

but it does not work. Here's my attempt on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b7qnrsrz/3/

Thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: `console.log($(this).css('opacity'))`? It's likely because of floating point numbers should be compared carefully

Comment: @zerkms `0.300000011920929`

Comment: I'm pretty sure to edit CSS values, you have to use `$(selector).css('prop', 'value')` (or without the quotation marks if it's a number)

Comment: Try `toFixed`. I.e. `$(this).css("opacity").toFixed(2);` rounds to 2 decimal places

Comment: @Firedrake969 I think he's not editing, but checking.
The problem seems to be it being not exactly 3. ArtOfCode's solution will probably fix it.

Comment: just want to thank you all for taking the time to look at this. you've taught me a lot with a few different options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do what everyone else is saying, or since you're only dealing with two case (positive/negative test), you could use `==1` and `!=1`, instead of `==.3`.  Also, it's *jQuery*, make sure to use `.stop()` with transitions/animations.

http://jsfiddle.net/b7qnrsrz/16/

Comment: You need more logic in your function.  Every time you scroll you're calling the function, which is stacking the event (and adding time).  Using `stop(true,true)` usually would be an answer, however you don't want the animation completing immediately.  Therefore you need code to detect current animations, and not stack them, but to change the animation if it goes beyond the scope of the window.

Comment: This seemed to be the simplest solution. Thanks! I modified it a bit, because of a delay in the animation, so I took out the if statement's '.stop()' and it appears to be working exactly as intended. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7qnrsrz/20/)

Comment: The reason I put those in there was for when you scrolled up and down very quickly.  Try it out and take notice to what happens when you do.  Nevermind, I thought you took it out of both and it seems you only took it out of the one, so it might work.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that floating point numbers in JavaScript are not always strictly `.3` or `.5`, some other digits get added to the end as well. Try putting the first condition on top, and jump to the other if it's false, since it theory, you shouldn't have other states.

I would also suggest assigning `$(this)` to a variable to prevent jQuery from having to create an instance of the same element 3 times.

```
var $this = $(this),
    opacity = $this.css('opacity');
if (objectBottom < windowBottom){
    if (opacity != 1) $this.stop().fadeTo(500,1);
}
else if (opacity == 1) $this.stop().fadeTo(500,.3);
```

I also added [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), because if someone is scrolling up and down rapidly for whatever reason, the animation queue on the element may fill up and cause a pulsing effect due to all fading animations still being in the queue. Stop prevents this by clearing the animations from the queue, and thus executing the following animation instantaneously.

Also, this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {fade();});
```

can be shortened just to

```
$(window).scroll(fade);
```

Working example:

```js
$(window).on("load",function() {
    function fade() {
        $('.fade').each(function() {
            var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight(),
                windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight(),
                $this = $(this),
                opacity = $this.css('opacity');
            
            if (objectBottom < windowBottom){
                if (opacity != 1) $this.fadeTo(500,1);
            }
            else if (opacity == 1) $this.fadeTo(500,.3);
        });
    }
    fade();
    $(window).scroll(fade); //Fade in elements during scroll
});
```

```css
.fade {
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 01</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 02</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 03</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 04</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 05</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 06</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 07</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 08</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 09</div>
    <div class="fade">Fade In 10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating points are subject to imprecision, for more info, go to [floating-point-gui.de](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

What you need to do is use a "epsilon": a acceptable range of difference of your desired and the actual value.

```
abs(VALUE) - COMPARE < EPSILON
```

So your comparsion should be:

```
Math.abs($(this).css('opacity')) - .3 < 0.01
```

For a 0.01 acceptable error. This might be more specific, but I don't think it would be necessary for this case.

Comment: You should probably wrap the left side in an absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

Just use javascript `Math` to get the opacity value with one decimal:

```
if (Math.round($(this).css('opacity') * 10) / 10 == .3) {
  $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
}
```

Comment: @miminographite if you will use this solvation, than ure able to use different opacity options, because the if else just give you 2 options... just want you to keep that in mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
    $('.fade').each(function () {
        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();

        var opacityPercentage = parseInt($(this).css("opacity") * 100);
        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it in */
        if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { //object comes into view (scrolling down)
            if (opacityPercentage == 30) {
                $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
            }
        } else { //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
            if (opacityPercentage == 100) {
                $(this).fadeTo(500, 0.3);
            }
        }
    });
```