# Fix delayed jquery fade on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

vol7ron showed me how to achieve an effect where an element fades in on scroll down, and fades out on scroll up here: [Why does "($(this).css('opacity')==.3)" not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704637/why-does-this-cssopacity-3-not-work/26705686#26705686)

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b7qnrsrz/16/

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    function fade() {
        $('.fade').each(function () {
            /* Check the location of each desired element */
            var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it in */
            if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { //object comes into view (scrolling down)
                if ($(this).css('opacity') != 1) {
                    $(this).stop(true,false).fadeTo(500, 1);
                }
            } else { //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
                if ($(this).css('opacity') == 1) {
                    $(this).stop(true,false).fadeTo(500, .3);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    fade(); //Fade in completely visible elements during page-load
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        fade();
    }); //Fade in elements during scroll
    });
```

This works almost perfectly. As is, the boxes wait to fade until I've stopped scrolling. So if I smoothly scroll past three of them, rather than fading one-by-one as I scroll past each one, they all wait to fade in until after I stop scrolling. How can I remedy this so that fade triggers even while scrolling, not waiting until after stopping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there is a *bug* in the script.

Every time you scroll it executes the fade function. Because the animation is prefixed with a `stop()` the animation never really gets any time to run if you scroll slowly.

You can either remove the `.stop()` or find a way to only apply the fade-in to elements that are not already fading in.

---

There seems to be another bug. Sometimes items are not detected as being in the viewport and they will not fade in. I'm not sure why that happens. It might have something to do with scrolling really fast.

Comment: Thanks so much! I ended up removing the '.stop()' just from the if statement, but leaving it for the else and it gave me the desired result. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7qnrsrz/20/)