# JQuery "fade out" effect on scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code, if scroll down Fade in and show the object

css:

```
.fadeInBlock {
    opacity:0;    
}
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll( function(){
        $('.fadeInBlock').each( function(i){            
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            /* Adjust the "200" to either have a delay or that the content starts fading a bit before you reach it  */
            bottom_of_window = bottom_of_window + 200;
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
            }
        }); 

    });
});
```

and need solution to fade out the object after scroll up.

Please advise, thank you

Comment: What is problem? What you want to happen? What you see happen instead? me tarzan you jane

Comment: Hi, i need a fade out effect (or hide the .fadeInblock)  if i scroll up

Comment: you need a fade out effect ... yet your code only refers to fade in .. maybe you need to `animate({opacity:0}, 500)`

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/mwtebtw9/5/ , after scroll down show the object, i need if we scroll up fade out the object or hide

Comment: do the reverse of what you do now ... that can't be too hard ... if you wrote the code you posted, the inverse of that code should be obvious to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this will help

```
function isVisible(elem){
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log('scroll')
  $('.fadeInBlock').each(function(i) {
    if (isVisible(this)) {
      $(this).animate({
        'opacity': '1'
      }, 1000);
    } else {
        $(this).css({
        'opacity': '0'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/32feyrhy/4/

Comment: Sorry, i have renamed function(
now it works on updated link

Comment: what icon do you mean?

Comment: the left smallest logo in menubar

Comment: you can do this with css. For exsmple your icon have .fadeInBlock class so
`.fadeInBlock{
 opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 300ms ease;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .fadeInBlock{
 opacity: 1;
}
`

Comment: yes, it is only css. You can remove js code for this. It is better to use ccs when you can (jquery solutions are slow and complicated)

Comment: Thank you for solution! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

---

```
$(window).on("load",function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".fade").each(function() {
      /* Check the location of each desired element */
      var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      var windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();

      /* If the element is completely within bounds of the window, fade it in */
      if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { //object comes into view (scrolling down)
        if ($(this).css("opacity")==0) {$(this).fadeTo(500,1);}
      } else { //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
        if ($(this).css("opacity")==1) {$(this).fadeTo(500,0);}
      }
    });
  }); $(window).scroll(); //invoke scroll-handler on page-load
});
```

---

```
.fade {
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

---

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 01</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 02</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 03</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 04</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 05</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 06</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 07</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 08</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 09</div>
  <div class="fade">Fade In 10</div>
</div>
```

Please check this link:-[Fade In on Scroll Down, Fade Out on Scroll Up - based on element position in window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694385/fade-in-on-scroll-down-fade-out-on-scroll-up-based-on-element-position-in-win)