# Fade in and out when scroll up and down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to extend the code provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26697397/9778946) answer. The code there fades in an element when scrolling down and fades out an image when scrolling up but doesn't fade out when scrolling down. I want to implement all elements: fade in when scrolling down, fade out as element leaves the viewport, fade in when scrolling up and fade out as element leaves the viewport.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using `jQuery` and `scroll` event listener, you can use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to achieve the desired result.

You can adjust the `threshold` option of the `IntersectionObserver` according to your needs. This option is used to indicate at what percentage of the target's visibility the observer's callback should be executed. I have set it to 70%.

```js
const observerOptions = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: "0px",
  threshold: 0.7
};

function observerCallback(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      // fade in observed elements that are in view
      entry.target.classList.replace('fadeOut', 'fadeIn');
    } else {
      // fade out observed elements that are not in view
      entry.target.classList.replace('fadeIn', 'fadeOut');
    }
  });
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback, observerOptions);

const fadeElms = document.querySelectorAll('.fade');
fadeElms.forEach(el => observer.observe(el));
```

```css
.fade {
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in;
}

.fadeOut { opacity: 0; }
.fadeIn { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fade fadeOut">Element 1</div>
  <div class="fade fadeOut">Element 2</div>
  <div class="fade fadeOut">Element 3</div>
  <div class="fade fadeOut">Element 4</div>
  <div class="fade fadeOut">Element 5</div>
  <div class="fade fadeOut">Element 6</div>
  <div class="fade fadeOut">Element 7</div>
  <div class="fade fadeOut">Element 8</div>
  <div class="fade fadeOut">Element 9</div>
  <div class="fade fadeOut">Element 10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This didnt work for me. Brave v1.45.118 (Chromium 107)