# updating function when nav link is clicked

Tags: javascript, css

Hello I have a feature where when you click a link in the navigation the content of the body switches and I was combining it with a little script from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694385/fade-in-on-scroll-down-fade-out-on-scroll-up-based-on-element-position-in-win) question and it works great. The only thing is that if you click a link and don't scroll the images won't show up unless you scroll at least 1px. So I was wondering if there's a fix for this. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HcJanni/Ly43va05/).

Side question: Would it be possible to wait for the content to show up until the page is fully scrolled up?

Script:

```
$(window).on("load",function() {
  function fade(pageLoad) {
    var windowTop=$(window).scrollTop(), windowBottom=windowTop+$(window).innerHeight();
    var min=0, max=1, threshold=0.01;
    
    $(".fade").each(function() {
      /* Check the location of each desired element */
      var objectHeight=$(this).outerHeight(), objectTop=$(this).offset().top, objectBottom=$(this).offset().top+objectHeight;
      
      /* Fade element in/out based on its visible percentage */
      if (objectTop < windowTop) {
        if (objectBottom > windowTop) {$(this).fadeTo(0,min+((max-min)*((objectBottom-windowTop)/objectHeight)));}
        else if ($(this).css("opacity")>=min+threshold || pageLoad) {$(this).fadeTo(0,min);}
      } else if (objectBottom > windowBottom) {
        if (objectTop < windowBottom) {$(this).fadeTo(0,min+((max-min)*((windowBottom-objectTop)/objectHeight)));}
        else if ($(this).css("opacity")>=min+threshold || pageLoad) {$(this).fadeTo(0,min);}
      } else if ($(this).css("opacity")<=max-threshold || pageLoad) {$(this).fadeTo(0,max);}
    });
  } fade(true); //fade elements on page-load
  $(window).scroll(function(){fade(false);}); //fade elements on scroll
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by taking `fade` method outside the `load event listener` that will make it available everywhere. And then call it from on the click of `nav buttons`.

See the js below:

```
$(window).on("load",function() {
 this.fade(true); //fade elements on page-load
  $(window).scroll(function(){this.fade(false);}); //fade elements on scroll
});

//Take below fade method outside of the load event listener.

  function fade(pageLoad) {
    var windowTop=$(window).scrollTop(), windowBottom=windowTop+$(window).innerHeight();
    var min=0, max=1, threshold=0.01;
    
    $(".fade").each(function() {
      /* Check the location of each desired element */
      var objectHeight=$(this).outerHeight(), objectTop=$(this).offset().top, objectBottom=$(this).offset().top+objectHeight;
      
      /* Fade element in/out based on its visible percentage */
      if (objectTop < windowTop) {
        if (objectBottom > windowTop) {$(this).fadeTo(0,min+((max-min)*((objectBottom-windowTop)/objectHeight)));}
        else if ($(this).css("opacity")>=min+threshold || pageLoad) {$(this).fadeTo(0,min);}
      } else if (objectBottom > windowBottom) {
        if (objectTop < windowBottom) {$(this).fadeTo(0,min+((max-min)*((windowBottom-objectTop)/objectHeight)));}
        else if ($(this).css("opacity")>=min+threshold || pageLoad) {$(this).fadeTo(0,min);}
      } else if ($(this).css("opacity")<=max-threshold || pageLoad) {$(this).fadeTo(0,max);}
      
    });
  }

    
// change activenav class, show the clicked element only and hide the others https://codepen.io/MohdHussein/pen/MWKEvdp


// grab all the buttons
let Buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".selectSection button");

// loop through the buttons using for..of 
for (let button of Buttons) {
  // listen for a click event 
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // et = event target
    const et = e.target;
    // slect activenav class
    const activenav = document.querySelector(".activenav");
    // check for the button that has activenav class and remove it
    if (activenav) {
      activenav.classList.remove("activenav");
    }
    // add activenav class to the clicked element 
    et.classList.add("activenav");

    // select all classes with the name content
    let allContent = document.querySelectorAll('.contentsec');

    // loop through all content classes
    for (let contentsec of allContent) {
      // display the content if the class has the same data-attribute as the button 
      if (contentsec.getAttribute('data-number') === button.getAttribute('data-number')) {
        contentsec.style.display = "block";
      }
      // if it's not equal then hide it.
      else {
        contentsec.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    this.fade(true); //Call fade method on click 
  });
}
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/ormdxejp/).